# Cannot display two scrollview together in stacklayout in Xamarin Forms

Tags: scrollview, xamarin.forms

I try to add two horizontal scrollviews together in one stacklayout. But displayed only last scrollview(`scrollView1`). Why first `scrollView` doesn't display?

```
var avatarLayout = new StackLayout()
            {
               HeightRequest = 500,
            };

StackLayout st = new StackLayout()
                {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
                };
                st.Children.Add(postImage1);
                st.Children.Add(postImage2);
                st.Children.Add(postImage3);

StackLayout st1 = new StackLayout()
                {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
                };
                st1.Children.Add(postImage4);
                st1.Children.Add(postImage5);
                st1.Children.Add(postImage6);

                ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView()
                    {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                    Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
                    Content = new StackLayout{
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        Children = {st}
                    }
                };

                ScrollView scrollView1 = new ScrollView()
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                    Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
                    Content = new StackLayout
                    {
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        Children = {st1}
                    }
                };
                avatarLayout.Children.Add(avatarImage);
                avatarLayout.Children.Add(friends);
                avatarLayout.Children.Add(scrollView);
                avatarLayout.Children.Add(cars);
                avatarLayout.Children.Add(scrollView1);
                avatarLayout.Children.Add(posts1);
```

**Solved.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above isn't adding any children to st1, so scrollView1 don't have anything to display.  It looks like the code ought to be displaying scrollView (not scrollView1), but with the content that was intended for both ScrollView containers.  I suspect the calls after the creation of st1 should be st1.Children.Add(...) not st.Children.Add(...).